# PHP including large files - memory problems

Tags: php, memory-management, server-side-includes

I am having issues with including really large files and so have used `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`
but still cannot include a file that is just over 1GB.  What should I do?

Comment: What kind of file would you want to include that's over 1GB? Is this some kind of large array? Have you considered trying to read in the data in chunks?

Comment: What you should do is not include a file that's 1GB in size. I won't even bother asking why, it's visible from a mile away you got a problem with the architecture of your app.

Comment: My script generates products feeds for users.  It looks to see if a .txt file exists, if it does, it includes the file, if it doesn't it generates the file.  Sometimes the files are huge depending on how many products the user has.

Comment: That's wrong design then. `include` directive is used to evaluate a piece of code that PHP can execute. It has to be parsed by the lexer and turned into opcode for later execution. Including a feed in a PHP file is pointless since you're not executing any PHP code, you're trying to output some product fees (I can only assume it's some textual output, be it xml or csv). What you should do is use chunked output using `fopen()`, `fread` and `print` functions. Open the file and output chunks of several kilobytes at a time. To output a gig feed will take some time, both to output and to download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to reconsider your architecture; PHP's [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function was not designed to handle such large files; it was designed to include and evaluate a PHP code file. Without knowing what data the file actually holds, it's hard to say more; but it seems very unlikely that this file actually only holds PHP code; it sounds like you're trying to read a lot of information which is encoded in a PHP-like format.

You should e.g. try to [read the file in chunks or lines](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-readfiles/) instead of using include.

Answer (score -1):

The only possible reason you would be trying to load such a file is to probably import it into a database. Each database has a file loader that is meant for this purpose. Mysql has LOAD INFILE specifically to deal with this issue. I'd recommend getting the data in your database first, then use PHP or MySQL to transform the data to your needs. Using PHP to parse through a 1GB file is probably not the best usage of PHP or your resources.